# Mysql character set and collation value change

Tags: mysql

I have a table temp. I applied new character set and collation in MYSQL with following query:

```
ALTER TABLE temp CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Now I want to revert this back to what the table was before I changed the attributes. Is there a way I can do that?

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not without knowing what the previous value was. I think the default charset for mysql is `latin1` and the default collation is case-insensitive ([`latin1_swedish_ci` for `latin1`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-server.html))